# Is there ever a reason to promote to a bishop? If so, what is it?

Tags: bishops, pawn-promotion

Is there ever a reason to promote to a bishop? If so, what is it? I understand why one would promote to a queen, rook, or knight. I won't go into why here, see other questions. But why would one ever promote to a bishop? Not to show off, there must be a real reason that promoting to a queen, rook, or knight would all be worse.

Comment: Please learn to use the Search function in the top left hand corner of the screen

Comment: some people do this to mock opponent for not resigning in a totally lost position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason is to avoid stalemate. Suppose you are playing blitz chess and you don't have much time left. In hurry, you can't think much so you choose to promote to bishop. So chances of stalemate decreases.